# Android volley exception: org.json.JSONException: Value <br><table of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: java, android, json, android-volley

I try to put data into my db, but I have exception like in the topic. Probably it is the problem with convert String to JSONObject, but I have no idea how can I fix that.

Here is my `OrderRequest`:

```
public OrderRequest(String orderNumber, String date, String adress, int phone, String email, String orderCode, int price, String time, int state, Response.Listener<String> listener){
        super(Method.POST, ORDER_REQUEST_URL, listener, null);
    params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("ordernumber", orderNumber);
    params.put("data", date);
    params.put("adress", adress);
    params.put("phone", phone + "");
    params.put("email", email);
    params.put("ordercode", orderCode);
    params.put("price", price + "");
    params.put("time", time);
    params.put("state", state + "");

}
@Override
public Map<String, String> getParams(){
    return params;
}
```

Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php
$con = <-here is password, etc...


$ordernumber = $_POST["ordernumber"];
$date = $_POST["date"];
$adress = $_POST["adress"];
$phone = $_POST["phone"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$ordercode = $_POST["ordercode"];
$price = $_POST["price"];
$time = $_POST["time"];
$state = $_POST["state"];


$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO order (ordernumber, date, adress, phone, email, ordercode, price, time, state) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "sssissisi", $ordernumber, $date, $adress, $phone, $email, $ordercode, $price, $time, $state);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

$response = array();
$response["success"] = true;  

echo json_encode($response);
```

?>

Here is my Java code:

```
                    Response.Listener<String> responsListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {
                            try {
                                JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                                boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");

                                if (success) {
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(FinalizeActivity.this, LoggedActivity.class);
                                    FinalizeActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                                } else {

                                }
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    };

                    OrderRequest orderRequest = new OrderRequest(orderNumberO, dateO, adressO, phoneO, emailO, orderCodeO, priceO, timeO, stateO, responsListener);
                    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(FinalizeActivity.this);
                    queue.add(orderRequest);
                }
            }
        });
```

In other place in my application I have a similar code, and then it works.

Comment: You're echoing HTML somewhere, that's what your exception is telling you. As HTML cannot be parsed as JSON, you get an exception

Comment: it's `data` not `date` look for typos in php code

Comment: you get a response with HTML content and in this line ` new JSONObject(response);` it cannot convert it. first findout what is your response then if it is in json format, convert it

Answer (score 0):

UTF-8 encoding on both sides.

- Php code Notepad++ and select Encode in utf-8 without BOM from Encoding tab and running this code
- PHP side: header('Content-type=application/json; charset=utf-8');

Comment: in Notepad++ i select option Encode in utf-8 w/o BOM. But what shoudl i do with this: header('Content-type=application/json; charset=utf-8');      i should place it in php code?

Comment: if problem still continues yes you should place this php code.

Answer (score -1):

> you must have some error which gives HTML ,  you can easily check same request using postman app where we can see error [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/)